# AWS Load Balancer https configure not working

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have created Load Balancer on AWS EC2. But when I open URL with https I get such error:

ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I have port following port conf. for LB

[image]

My app is running on port 3000. Can anyone help to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

port 80 should redirect to port 443

443 should talk to an endpoints using port 3000

please remember about opening up relevant ports on security groups.